# How to display JS objects in view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

There is already a question from our friend Vinicius Scaramel with this problem, but there is no answer solution, so come on:

I'm getting an object in JSON format via http.get on Ionic, (using AngularJS), but when viewing it in the view with {{}} it only displays [object Object], and it does not display my object itself. I'm already losing my hair trying to solve. Let's code it:

Role of my provider who gives the GET

```
 getChamadoSelecionado(){
    return this.http.get(this.LINK + "/chamadoSelecionado");
  }
```

my array receiving my object through GET

```
ionViewDidLoad() { //funcao que é executada quando abre a view
  console.log('ionViewDidLoad ChamadoPage');
  this.ChamadosProvider.getChamadoSelecionado().subscribe(    // chamando minha funcao que da o GET na minha api, e retorna o objeto
    data => {
      const objeto_retorno = JSON.parse((data as any)._body); // inserindo na variavel os dados que preciso que estão em data._body (convertido em objeto atraves do JSON.parse)
      this.objetoChamadoSelecionado = objeto_retorno;   //atribuindo o objeto ao meu array
      console.log(this.objetoChamadoSelecionado);    
      }, error => {
        console.log(error);
      })
    }
```

so far everything is running very well, giving a console.log in my variable that received the return of JSON is beautiful:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvxEU.png)

My View's Code

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Chamado</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding >

<div ><p>{{objetoChamadoSelecionado}}</p></div>


</ion-content>
```

This is where it should display my object, but it displays only this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwpZJ.png)

also does not work:

> objetoChamadoSelecionado.numero

for example, and I can not get anything ... The strangest thing of all is that on another page I have a return from a list of objects, using a * ngFor works normal ...

Answer (score 4):

Use `json` pipe to see the object with properties

```
<div><p>{{ objetoChamadoSelecionado | json }}</p></div>
```

Or access it properties as you mentioned above, but your `objetoChamadoSelecionado` must be initialized first. Without it will give you an error while data is not set.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, my return was this: {  "{\n  \"numero\": 34561,\n  \"cliente\": \"Alison Tecnologia\",\n  \"usuario\": \"Jose\",\n  \"assunto\": \"Internet fora\",\n  \"situacao\": \"Em Analise\",\n  \"tecnico\": \"Maria\"\n}": ""}, 
it looks like the formatting is wrong?  and I'm sorry for the lack of knowledge, but what did you mean by initializing?

Comment: Give to it a default value. In the controller objetoChamadoSelecionado = {};